# Joining tables and replacing null values with specified values

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

I am trying to make a printable page, where there is all the sales of a specified manufacturer, listing all the products, between specified dates. If there has not been any sales, it should display 0.

The tables

```
// Manufacturer table
// mid, manufacturer
// Products table
// pid, product, ref_manufacturer_id
// Orders table
// oid, orderPrice, orderDateTime, ref_product_id
```

And the query that works (without date limitation)

```
SELECT prod.product, COALESCE(COUNT(pord.oid),0) AS orderCount,
COALESCE(SUM(pord.orderPrice),0) AS orderSum
FROM product_manufacturer AS manu
JOIN product_list AS prod ON prod.ref_manufacturer_id = manu.mid
LEFT JOIN product_orders AS pord ON pord.ref_product_id = prod.pid
WHERE manu.mid = :manu_id
GROUP BY prod.product;
```

But as soon as I add into the WHERE-syntax this

```
WHERE manu.mid = :manu_id AND DATE(pord.orderDateTime) BETWEEN :orders_start AND :orders_end
```

I am using PHP PDO on connecting and verifying that the manu_id is int and the orders_start/end is converted to MySQL date format.

But the question I am trying to fidn out is, what is causing the problem, that when I add the date restriction, every product that was not ordered, is not displayed on the output?

SQL on creating the tables

```
CREATE TABLE product_list (
  pid bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  product varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  ref_manufacturer_id bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (pid),
  KEY ref_manufacturer_id (ref_manufacturer_id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;

CREATE TABLE product_manufacturer (
  mid bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  manufacturer varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (mid),
  UNIQUE KEY manufacturer (manufacturer)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;

CREATE TABLE product_orders (
  oid bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  orderPrice float(10,2) NOT NULL,
  orderDatetime timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  red_product_id bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (oid),
  KEY red_product_id (red_product_id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need is to move the `orderDateTime` criteria to the join clause instead of where clause like:

```
SELECT prod.product, COALESCE(COUNT(pord.oid),0) AS orderCount,
       COALESCE(SUM(pord.orderPrice),0) AS orderSum
FROM product_manufacturer AS manu
JOIN product_list AS prod ON prod.ref_manufacturer_id = manu.mid
LEFT JOIN product_orders AS pord 
          ON pord.ref_product_id = prod.pid
          AND DATE(pord.orderDateTime) BETWEEN :orders_start AND :orders_end
WHERE manu.mid = :manu_id
GROUP BY prod.product;
```

The reason it does not work within the `WHERE` clause is because of the `NULL` values returned from the outer join. When you do not have a row in `product_orders` fot a product, the outer join returns a NULL for the date field `orderDateTime` and that row will be filtered out because a `NULL` is not equal to anything.

Comment: Much simpler than what Michał Powaga set. Thank you for this.

Comment: You could (or should) replace `DATE(pord.orderDateTime) BETWEEN :orders_start AND :orders_end` with `(pord.orderDateTime >= :orders_start) AND (pord.orderDateTime < orders_end + INTERVAL 1 DAY)` so the query doesn't have to do a full scan of the `pord` table.

Comment: (I guess the 2 parameters are dates).

Comment: @ypercube, Why should(if so) I do that??

Comment: So the query doesn't have to do a full scan of the `pord` table. If you have a big order table, the query, as it is, will have to call the `DATE()` function for **every** row and check the condition, too. If you use the equivalent there is no call to `DATE()` and (if there is a suitable index), the query will use the index and only scan the index or read the needed rows.

Comment: @ypercube, I assumed the 2 parameters are dates, but thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
SELECT p.product, 
    COALESCE(o.orderCount, 0) as orderCount, 
    COALESCE(o.orderSum,0) AS orderSum
FROM product_manufacturer AS m
JOIN product_list AS p ON p.ref_manufacturer_id = m.mid
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT ref_product_id as pid, COUNT(oid) AS orderCount, SUM(orderPrice) AS orderSum
    FROM product_orders
    WHERE DATE(orderDateTime) BETWEEN :orders_start AND :orders_end
    GROUP BY ref_product_id
) AS o ON p.pid = o.pid
WHERE m.mid = :manu_id
```

**Edit**: Corrected after ypercube comment.

Comment: You only need the `product_orders` in the subquery, not the `product_list`.

Comment: and `DATE(p.orderDateTime)` should be: `DATE(o.orderDateTime)`. Similarly `GROUP BY p.pid` -> `GROUP BY o.ref_product_id`

Comment: @ypercube I've noticed `group by` after your comment about "orderDateTime" but you were quicker :-). Now I think that everything is fine :-).

Answer (score 0):

try this on the where clause.

```
WHERE manu.mid = :manu_id AND (DATE(pord.orderDateTime) BETWEEN :orders_start AND :orders_end)
```

It might be reading the second AND function as another where clause that the statement should return true. Just a hunch on that. Let me know if this does the trick.

Comment: Didn't work, still continues to show only the products that have orders between those dates. And ignoring the ones that don't have.

Comment: maybe because we the where clause defines that the date should be inside orders start and orders end. It should really ignore those other facts. Please explain what you want to do.

Comment: I want to display all the products from a specific manufacturer and the product orders between specified dates, where the manufacturer is the specified.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how your specific system works, but it may be `orderDateTime` is not set (ie, `NULL` or something else) until that product gets ordered.  You may want to try:

`WHERE manu.mid = :manu_id AND ((DATE(pord.orderDateTime) BETWEEN :orders_start AND :orders_end) OR pord.orderDateTime=NULL)`

If this is not the case, could you give an example of the `orderDateTime` value for something that is not showing up when you want it to?